# send post and get request on click using NEXT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i need to post and get my data when clicking on the same button [like write and show comment] , but when i click the button everything is going well but a request with 304 status code is running with infinite loop, can someone help ?

```
    const addCommentHandler = (commentData) => {
        axios({
          url: `/api/comment/${eventId}`,
          method: "post",
          data: commentData,
    
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
        }).then((res) => {
          const data = res.data;
          console.log(data);
        });
    
        axios({
          url: `/api/comment/${eventId}`,
          method: "get",
        }).then((res) => {
          const data = res.data;
          setComments(data.comments);
        });
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        addCommentHandler();
      }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like You want to Post the Data and then want to get the Updated Comments.But you are creating Two Asynchronous Api Calls..

304 Status Code Means " The requested resource has not been modified since the last time you accessed it "

Please Refresh Cache and try Again..

```
  const addCommentHandler = async (commentData) => {
   // add Try Catch for Errors..
   const responseData = await axios({
      url: `/api/comment/${eventId}`,
      method: "post",
      data: commentData,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    })

    const resData = await axios({
      url: `/api/comment/${eventId}`,
      method: "get",
    })

   setComments(resData.data.comments);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Pass CommentData as Params in addCommentHandler
    addCommentHandler();
  }, []);`
```

Comment: thank you it helped but i can't fetch comments on load, the params is in another components, i pass the  addCommentHandler through props